# Convert a delimited string to a dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, delimiter

I have a string in the format

```
=key1=value1=key2=value2=key3=value3
```

I need to convert it to a `Dictionary<string,string>` for the above mentioned key value pairs.
What would be the best way to go about this?

I've tried this:

```
var input = "key1=value1=key2=value2=key3=value3";
var dict = Regex.Matches(input , @"\s*(.*?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*(=|$)")
                .OfType<Match>()
                .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Comment: All one line (no linefeeds/carriage returns or other whitespace for that matter)?  All delimited by equals characters, no chance that the key or the value could contain an equals?

Comment: Create a function that parses the string and splits the string on `=` then you need to determine whether you are on a key or value then plug them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a little Linq:

```
"=key1=value1=key2=value2=key3=value3"
    .Split('=')                            // Split into an array of strings
    .Skip(1)                               // Skip the first (empty) value
    .Select((v, i) => new { v, i })        // Get value and index
    .GroupBy(x => x.i / 2)                 // Group every pair together
    .ToDictionary(g => g.First().v,        // First item in group is the key
                  g => g.Last().v)         // Last item in group is the value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>(); 

var input = str.Split(new [] { '=' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for(int i=0; i<input.Length; i+=2)
{ 
    dict.Add(input[i], input[i+1]);
}
```